# What's the difference between “turn out” and “end up”?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know when I should use **"turn out"** and **"end up"**. I notice that "end up" is more universal than "turn out".

See an example:

> I’m sure it will all turn out well in the end.

or

> I’m sure it will all end up OK in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out is generally used to convey something unexpected, while end up conveys  the idea of a final outcome of a series of previous  steps:

[Turn out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/turn-out)

> to happen in a particular way or to have a particular result, especially an unexpected one:
>
> - As events turned out, we were right to have decided to leave early.
>     How did the recipe turn out?
>     ​

[End up:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/end-up)

> to finally be in a particular place or situation:
>
> - They're travelling across Europe by train and are planning to end up in Moscow.
> - Much of this meat will probably end up as dog food.
>     [ L ] She'll end up penniless if she continues to spend like that.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

It will turn out well in the end, despite people don’t think so.

It will end up well on the end, after all the efforts  we made.

Comment: **despite people don’t think so.** doesn't work! Possibly **despite what people think**. And those commas are redundant!